# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider flutter

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, dart, provider

there is an alternative to this?

```
    return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: Auth(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      update: (context, auth, previousProd) {
        return Products(
            auth.token, previousProd == null ? [] : previousProd.items);
      },
    ),
```

acording with the oficial docs it is not the best practice use update whithout create, but i need to pass my auth token forward for optain the products from firebase, sorry i am learning with out dated videos and they use the former builder argument thas is currenly out to date.

PD: My english is bad

Comment: There are two things that caught my attention in your code. Don't use Provider.value() and you don't need to pass your auth token around. You can easily obtain it in any screen. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201378/how-to-get-the-token-from-firebase-auth

Comment: I al not using firebase SDK, mi code is for any backend...I think that can't apply that example by the other hand acording with documentation can use value if muy provider IS created previusly ?? Please correcto me if i am wron