# Storing session data in flutter across pages best practice

Tags: flutter, security, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

I have a Flutter app which holds a username and a token to communicate with a web service.
How can I manage the username and token efficiently using best practices? Currently I am writing them into a DB and select them each time I want to do a request.

I tried to use bloc provider [flutter bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) with a BlocProvider. I have the states LoggedIn and LoggedOut and the events Login and Logout.

Furthermore, I had a look at
[secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage), but I can't get the data available throughout all pages.

Also, I am not using the firebase API.

Let me know if I should provide some code snippets.

Comment: In my apps i just both shared preferences and a singleton class to store the user values upon login

Comment: I think firebase authentication would be simpler and more secure. It is free. You could send user's id tokens to your web server to verify which user sent it. https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-authentication-in-flutter-50e8b81cb29f and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens . You could get id tokens by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201378/how-to-get-the-token-from-firebase-auth

Comment: I checked out firebase and I don't think it is the always goto. First of all, my backend is done already (consisting of a relatively rich REST API). Second, firebase is not free at all if you have more traffic than just me testing the system.  Correct me if I am wrong, but to start from scratch in firebase looks like it is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example) now. The API is very simple and I wrote a wrapper to get rid of the (Strings) keys. Furthermore, the wrapper holds the values for the current session. The advantage of that is, that I can address the values directly instead of needing to read them asynchronously.